# ArrayList как параметр

Tags: java, arraylist

Нужно прочитать несколько файлов. Полные пути до них лежат в определённом ArrayList'е.

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(//сюда нужно воткнуть элементы Arraylist))) {
```

Что нужно сделать для того, чтоб программа принимала элементы ArrayList'а как параметры?

Comment: В цикле передавать

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for (File file : list) {
   try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) { ... }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Класс File соответствует одному файлу. Нужно обходить элементы ArrayList'а в цикле и для каждого выполнять необходимые операции.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант со `stream api`, для чтения содержимого файлов в списке `files`

```
files.stream()
     .flatMap(file -> {
                try {
                    return Files.lines(file.toPath());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return Stream.of("");
                }})
    .forEach(System.out::println);
```